# Biblioteca python asyncio

Tags: python, biblioteca

Olá, estou tentando instalar a biblioteca asyncio para Python 2.7.13 porém nao estou obtendo exito, segue o erro:

> rafamttz@rafamttz:~$ pip install asyncio`
>
> Collecting asyncio   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None,
>   read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(107, 'Transport endpoint
>   is not connected'))': /simple/asyncio/  Installing collected packages:
>   asyncio`
>
> Exception:  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/rafamttz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py",
>   line 215, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/home/rafamttz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py",
>   line 342, in run
>   prefix=options.prefix_path,   File "/home/rafamttz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py",
>   line 784, in install
>       **kwargs   File "/home/rafamttz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py",
>   line 851, in install
>       self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)   File
>   "/home/rafamttz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py",
>   line 1064, in move_wheel_files
>       isolated=self.isolated,File "/home/rafamttz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line
>   345, in move_wheel_files
>       clobber(source, lib_dir, True)   File "/home/rafamttz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line
>   316, in clobber
>       ensure_dir(destdir)   File "/home/rafamttz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py",
>   line 83, in ensure_dir
>       os.makedirs(path)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
>       mkdir(name, mode) OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/asyncio'

**Como faço para instalar essa biblioteca? O que é necessário?**

Comment: Ela só foi adicionada na versão 3.4. Por quê precisa utilizar a versão 2.7?

Comment: Bem, estou usando python 2.7 no meu servidor Crossbar.io (roteador WAMP/Web Socket), porem nunca tentei usar outra versão de python diferente da do servidor. tenho que conectar meu computador com o servidor

Comment: Não daria para usar a biblioteca Twisted?

Answer (score 3):

A recoemndação para desenvolvimento é usar o último Python - 3.6  - instalar o Python 3.6 no seu servidor é um problema trivial comparado com tentar criar usar código assincrono para Python 2.

Mas basicamente: quando a idéia de consolidar async no Python através da API do Asyncio surgiu, Python 2 já era obsoleto há alguns anos.
E não está ficando menos obsoleto agora.

No passado foi mantida uma biblioteca chamada Trollius especificamente para oferecer a mesma funcionalidade do "asyncio" (que então tinha o codinome "tulip" - "trollius" é o nome de uma outra flor).

Então mesmo que você contorne o problema desta questão e instale alguma versão do Asyncio ou biblioteca com alguma compatibilidade que funcione no Python 2, isso será de pouquissima serventia, já que nenhuma das bibliotecas Async para entrada e saida efetivas  (versões async para servir HTTP, ou se conectar com o banco de dados) vão funcionar em Python 2. - Para não falar em nenhum exemplo de código.

DIto tudo isso: mais ainda, provavelmente o seu servidor *tem* Python 3 -ou já instalado, ou disponível como pacote - é só uma questão de escrever "python3" em vez de Python.

De qualquer forma, o seu projeto deve fazer um uso de um "vitualenv": isso é um ambiente isolado em pastas do usuário (não do root), que tem versões próprias de cada biblioteca a ser usada - (isso eveitaria o erro acima, causado justamente por que o programa de instalação está querendo gravar os arquivos do asyncio em uma pasta do sistema - em `/usr/local`) .

Então - recomendaçoes gerais: leia alguma documentação sobre virtualenv. Pratique na sua máquina local - não precisa fazer direto no servidor. Se sua máquina local for Windows, ponha uma máquina virtual Linux: é menos complicado para desenvolver. Feito isso, e tendo inicado o projeto, se a versão doPython 3 no seu servidor for menor que a 3.6, compile um Python 3.6 bvocê mesmo lá - Python é um projeto relativametne fácil de compilar como usuário mesmo, sem interferir com o Python do sistema.

Crie o seu projeto de Python com versoinamento de arquivos, e de forma que funcione dentro de um virtualenv. Pronto - nesse ponto você está pronto para desenvolver um projeto que pode ir a produção,e usar biblitoecas atualizadas.

**atualização** 
A recomendação para código async, ou qualquer projeto de Python é sempre usar a última versão estável. No momento é a 3.7 e estamos a poucas semanas do lançamento oficial da 3.8. É comum as pessoas restringirem os projetos a versões antigas da linguagem por conta da versão do Python3 instalada no servidores - mesmo em servidores com dstribuições do tipo LTS como CentOS ou Ubuntu, o Python pode ser o 3.5 (de 4 anos atrás e sem muito dos recursos recentes).

O caminho a seguir nesses casos é ou instalar o Python3 mais recente a partir de algum repositório oficial, ou compilar o seu próprio Python 3  no destino. Isso é mais fácil de fazer do que soa - a minha recomendação é usar o projeto "[pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)" para cuidar disso. A partir do momento que você tem o Python mais novo, é só usa-lo para criar os ambientes virtuais (virtualenv ou equivalente) dos projetos, e vai funcionar sem diferença alguma para o Python3 nativo da distribuição, e com todas as dependencias criadas como arquivo de usuário, sem precisar nada do sistema, ou com root.

A única coisa é que a documentação do Pyenv parece não falar dos requisitos do sistema para compilar o Python3. Tanto o Ubuntu e outros Debian Based, quanto o CentOS e outros Redhat based tem a diretiva "builddep" do gerenciador de pacotes - o comando `apt builddep python3` (mais `apt install libcffi-dev` ou equivalente, no caso do Python do sistema ser menor que o 3.6), em geral é o suficiente para instalar tudo o que o sistema precisa para que o Pyenv possa compilar o Python 3 em qualquer versão desejada, sem dar nenhum erro.